# why the &#10 and &#32 in the placeholder attribute doesn't work in the browser

Tags: html, reactjs, placeholder

A question about how the `"&#10"` and "`&#32;`" work together in the placeholder attribute. Here is my code:

```
render() {
 return(
   <div>{
      if this.state.showTextarea?
      <div> 
        <form> 
         <textarea  placeholder='ex:&#10;{"data":{&#10;&#32;"name":"petter"&#10;}&#10;}'> </textarea>
        </form>
      </div>
      : null
   } 
   </div>
);
}
```

Here is the display:
[image]

It works very well if running on the code snippet, but it doesn't work in the browser(chrome and Edge).
Any idea?

Comment: Your code snippet has various issues which are probably typos but nevertheless make your question more unclear, so please fix these: duplicate `placeholder='placeholder='`, missing `</textarea>` close tag. And if it works here but not on your setup, try to find what's different between your setup and here, magic balls stopped working a few years back.

Comment: It's the typo problem. But still doesn't work

Comment: Show a full document's markup where this doesn't work.

Comment: This is the full markdown <textarea  placeholder='ex:&#10;{"data":{&#10;&#32;"name":"petter"&#10;}&#10;}'/> </textarea>. The layout is the same as I post, any idea?

Comment: **a full document's markup**, is this really all you have in your .html file? I want to see all you have, from the <!DOCTYPE html> to the  </html> (and I'd like to this in an [edit])

Comment: I update the full markup on the above. Thank you for the help, I use it for the react.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not part of the standard.  You can do it with Javascript. https://github.com/bradjasper/jQuery-Placeholder-Newlines

Comment: [It is part of the standards](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#attr-textarea-placeholder): "All U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN U+000A LINE FEED character pairs (CRLF) in the hint, as well as all other U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN (CR) and U+000A LINE FEED (LF) characters in the hint, must be treated as line breaks when rendering the hint."

Comment: It is NOT part of the standard.  U+000A means the literal line feed character.  That's not what we have here.  We have an entity that encodes a line feed.  It's different.

Comment: ... HTML attributes are decoded [at tokenization](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#attribute-value-(double-quoted)-state) (from the link follow the second bullet.) The link in my previous comment is about setting the value of that attribute, which happens after the tokenization. It is in the specs, what OP does ought to work, and it actually does.